# Batch file to run JMeter script

Tags: batch-file, jmeter

I have a .jmx file of all of my test plans and I want to create a batch file. When I click that, everything starts and ends automatically. So that I can provide it to my client as well to verify that I have performed the load test on his website. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jmeter [does not support running batch of .jmx files](http://ledohoanglong.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/running-jmeter-from-command-line/#comment-127) as document [part 2.4.3](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) (Command Line Mode) gives to us.
I would recommend you to try 2 approaches:

1) to follow best practices of [running jMeter in non GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode). 
In accordance to this approach you are expected to use the command

```
jmeter -n -t D:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl
```

Where the pareameters:

```
-n [This specifies JMeter is to run in non-gui mode]
-t  [name of JMX file that contains the Test Plan]
-l  [name of JTL file to log sample results to]
-j  [name of JMeter run log file]
```

2) to use any cloud service for running your .jmx file.

BlazeMeter (http://blazemeter.com/) worked for me fine.

[image: script settings setUp]
One can adjust the test plan settings.
Testing results can be seen on “Load Report” tab as soon as test finishes.
[image: test result]
For detalization one can follow [Getting Started: Scripting with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/get-started-scripting-jmeter)  steps.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: You can use ant for running multiple jmeter tests (multiple .jmx files)

Answer (score 1):

Just write the following command in a text file and save this file as `SomeName.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
jmeter -n -t "Your .jmx file path"  -l  "Your .jtl file path"
```

For example:

```
@echo off 

jmeter -n -t F:\DEV\WORKSPACE\buyer.jmx -l F:\DEV\WORKSPACE\output.jtl
```

After saving click on that bat file. The test plan result will be stored into .jtl file.

Note: Make sure you put this bat file into JmeterinstallationDirectory/bin folder.